# Issue with comparisons with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

The line with $mds>=$preco seems not to work, it always returns true or echo"COMPRADO"...

it should get me the other message when $mds is < $preco but it isn't

$preco is located in another file:

```
$preco = $row['pret'];
```

php:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT vnum, pret, attrtype0, attrvalue0, attrtype1, attrvalue1, attrtype2, attrvalue2, attrtype3, attrvalue3, attrtype4, attrvalue4, attrtype5, attrvalue5, attrtype6, attrvalue6, socket0, socket1, socket2 FROM dev_is_items WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1) {
    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass);
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("no database by that name");
    $mdsquery = mysql_query("SELECT coins FROM account.account WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $mds = mysql_fetch_object($mdsquery);
    if($mds>=$preco){
        echo "COMPRADO";
    }else{
        echo "MOEDAS INSUFICIENTES";
    }
```

Comment: what actually $mds and $preco is here, number or string... if number parse the data returned from sql to number and then compare

Comment: they are a number, and how do I do parse it?

Comment: It's almost as if `mysql_fetch_object()` is not returning a number, but... I don't know... maybe *an object* instead?

Comment: just do intval($mds->coins)>=$preco.. change int to whatever data type you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_object()` does not return the value of the `coins` field. It returns an object. If you want to check the value of the `coins` field, do this:

```
if ($mds->coins > $preco) { …
```

You should also know that `mysql_fetch_object` is deprecated. You should not use any of the `mysql_*` functions. Instead, use the `mysqli_*` functions or, even better, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

It’s good that you have used `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent a SQL injection attack. However, a better and more modern solution is to use PDO’s parameter binding. See the [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) method for an example.

Finally, there appears to be a logic error in your price check. I’ll assume `$preco` is the price of the item in coins, and `$coins` is the number of coins that the user has. If this is the case, then you want:

```
if ($mds->coins >= $preco) { …
```

Note the `>=`. Otherwise the user will not be able to purchase the item unless they have *more coins* than the cost of the item.